# When i try to set a text to a countdown timer it doesn't display

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
timeToCompleteCourse -= Time.deltaTime;
countDownText.text = "Time Left: " + timeToCompleteCourse.ToString();
```

This is the code i am using to countdown the timer and set the timer as a text, however when i play my scene in unity it only ever displays "Time Left:" not "Time Left: 12 (Or whatever number the countdown is currently at). IF anyone could help me it would be appreciated.

Comment: We will need more information than that, without knowing what type the variable "timeToCompleteCourse" is or "countDownText" is its impossible to say how they will interact. And thats not even mentioning needing to know how/where you are changing them. It would be best to post your entire script

Comment: Is it long enough to include the extra letters?

Comment: Yeah if timeToCompleteCourse is a float it’s likely that it’s attempting to display something like “Time Left: 12.0042”  and the number is too long to fit within the text bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the timer was 5 decimal places long and the text couldn't display that much, so i just rounded the countdown timer to fix the problem. Thanks BugFinder and Sven Viking for helping me solve this problem.